# how to call another python script in one python program?

Tags: python

Run.py is the script to initial the calculation and it calls function from dbm_utilities.py. Data_input.py is the script that needs to be executed in dbm_utilities.py in order to get the dataset for calculation.

How can we just execute Run.py and to get the results?

How to let Data_input.py run inside dbm_utilities.py based on the student ID and other variables provided in Run.py?

I just need some guidelines and suggestions about how to integrate my two little scripts (Run.py and Data_input.py) with dbm_utilities.py. Thanks.

```
# Run.py - the top layer that get results from dbm_utilities.py
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
unicode = type(u' ')


import warnings
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not sys.warnoptions:
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")    

# STEP 1: Testing condition    
    try:
        print('\nLoading testing condition ...')            
        
        quanity = 100.
        adjust = 0.2
        
    except RuntimeError:    
        print('\nTesting condition is not parameterized.')
    
    else:
        print('\nDone!')
    


# STEP: Student ID
    try:
        print('\nLoading student ID ...')
        ID = 'Michael'        
        
    except RuntimeError:    
        print('\nStudent ID is not parameterized.')

    else:
        print('\nDone!')    
        

# Run the calculation
    try:
        print('\nImporting calculation results ...')
        
        ID, Adjusted_AveScore = dbm_utilities.get_report(ID, quanity, adjust)
        
        print("Student Name:")
        print(ID)
        print("The score after adjustment:")
        print(Adjusted_AveScore)
        
    except RuntimeError:    
        print('\nModel is not running.')

    else:
        print('\nDone')
```

Run.py provides the parameters and student ID, and then call  dbm_utilities.get_report to get the final adjusted score.

```
# dbm_utilities.py - the middle layer that do the calculation
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)

# Get the ID, quanity, adjust from Run.py
        
def get_report(ID, quanity, adjust):

    if isinstance(substance, str) or isinstance(substance, unicode):
        
        ID, AveScore, Adjusted_AveScore = get_the_average(ID, adjust)
        
    if quanity < 100:

       print("Warning: student number is less than 100.")
    
    return (ID, Adjusted_AveScore)


# --- Utilities ---
def get_the_average(ID, adjust):

    AveScore = (Math + English + French + Sports) / 4.0
    Adjusted_AveScore = AveScore * adjust
    
    return (ID, AveScore, Adjusted_AveScore)
```

dbm_utilities.py gets the student ID and parameters from the Run.py for calculations and then return the results back to Run.py.

```
# Data_input.py - the lower layer to extract data from a database
# TODO: Get the ID from dbm_utillities.py
# For example:
# ID    = "Michael"

with open("./Scores.txt", 'r') as infile:
    text = infile.read().strip().split('\n')
header = text[0].split()[1:]
rows = [row.split() for row in text[1:]]
score_lib = {row[0]: [r for r in row[1:]] for row in rows}

def Math(ID):
    Math = (score_lib[ID][header.index("Math")])
    return float(Math)
def English(ID):
    English = (score_lib[ID][header.index("English")])
    return float(English)
def French(ID):
    French = (score_lib[ID][header.index("French")])
    return float(French)
def Sports(ID):
    Sports = (score_lib[ID][header.index("Sports")])
    return float(Sports)

Math = Math(ID)
English = English(ID)
French = French(ID)
Sports = Sports(ID)
```

Data_input.py is the script that read in the dataset and extract data based on the student ID. The student ID is provided in Run.py.

Here is the dataset:

```
ID                       Math   English   French  Sports
Michael                 100.0      57.0     73.0    90.0
Nancy                    90.0      66.0     91.0    85.0
Eva                      95.0      92.0     83.0    91.0
George                   64.0      47.0     71.0    67.0
Emma                     87.0      74.0     59.0    88.0
```

Scripts and dataset can be download at
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/id22danjnq6gobk/AAASf5e1mCJQPKB4z9bcg_ILa?dl=0

Comment: Can you clarify? You say `data_in.py` wants `oilID` from `utilties.py` (data_in depends on utilities) but then data_in results are used by utilities.py (utilites depends on data_in). Is `utilities.py` a top level script that takes command line input and gets a result? Or is `utilities.py` a module that can be imported? ... perhaps containing functions that were designed to be called by importers like your program?

Comment: Now, the utilites can run data_in.pyYes. data_in.py wants oilID from utilties.py

Comment: Now, by simply adding "import data_in", the utilites can run data_in.py. The data/file structure looks like this:  top level script is run.py, middle level program is utilties.py, the low level script is data_in.py. The oilID is given as a string in run.py. In run.py, oil, mass_flux = utilities.get_oil(substance, q_oil, gor, ca, T0) is calling utilities.  How can I let the utilities program knows the string from run.py?

Comment: @tdelaney please see revised question and my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang I think it might help to take a look at the guidelines for minimal reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example A link to the full code is helpful! But also, that's a big system to look at. See if you can reduce your code to the simplest possible version that reproduces the problem. Post that code *in your question*. Also, an explanation of your actual goal might help. I think you're trying to load data for an oil defined in a database other than the default, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I have made the minimal reproducible examples. Looking forward to learn some guideline to chain all of them together. Thanks.

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang See my edited answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In light of your comments and your edited question, I'm replacing my original answer.

---

It is usually best to not modify library scripts. That is, you probably shouldn't alter the code of `dbm_utilities`. However, you can set variables in it without modifying its source code.

Here's an example of an approach that could work. Try altering `Data_input.py` so that it contains a function that can be called with `ID`, something like this:

```
# Data_input.py

with open("./Scores.txt", 'r') as infile:
    text = infile.read().strip().split('\n')
header = text[0].split()[1:]
rows = [row.split() for row in text[1:]]
score_lib = {row[0]: [r for r in row[1:]] for row in rows}

def class_score(ID, subject):
    score = (score_lib[ID][header.index(subject)])
    return float(score)
```

Then, in `Run.py`, you import `data_input` to access the scores. You also import `dbm_utilities`, and *assign variables in its namespace*—without ever having to alter the utility file itself.

```
# Run.py

from data_input import class_score
import dbm_utilities

ID = 'Michael'
quantity = 100.
adjust = 0.2

dbm_utilities.Math = class_score(ID, "Math")
dbm_utilities.English = class_score(ID, "English")
dbm_utilities.French = class_score(ID, "French")
dbm_utilities.Sports = class_score(ID, "Sports")

ID, Adjusted_AveScore = dbm_utilities.get_report(ID, quantity, adjust)
        
print("Student Name:")
print(ID)
print("The score after adjustment:")
print(Adjusted_AveScore)
```

This means that `Run.py` is in charge of accessing and using what it needs from the other two scripts; neither of them ever has to import `Run.py` or each other.

Comment: This is a good answer except that we don't know enough about `utilities.py` to say whether its an importable module or not. It could just be a script and it could have a bunch of code run at module level that make it unsuitable for import. Hopefully OP will fill us in.

Comment: @CrazyChucky,  data_in.py is the simple script that process data that want to be used in utilities.py. In this case, I need to add "import data_in" to the program utilities.py.  Also, I need to add "from utilities import oilID" to my simple scrip data_in.py, so that oilID from utilities can be recognized. Is it correct?

Comment: I see oilID = 'Heavy_Oil' in utilities.py. I add from utilities import oilID in data_in.py. I got an error message: ImportError: cannot import name substance.

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang They probably should NOT import each other. That's called a circular import and is usually bad. But based on this and your other comment above, I'm now very unsure what you're trying to do. I'm also unsure how utilities.py and run.py are intended to be used. Does the creator have a website or GitHub or something to explain it?

Comment: The main program can be found at https://github.com/socolofs/tamoc/. Please see utilities.py as dbm_utilities.py in ./tamoc. The oilID here refers to substance in Line 77 in dbm_utilities.py. I now can import data_in to get the result in dbm_utilities.py. Another script is used to run this entire program and to also to give the oilID (substance). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang I'm glad that works, though that sounds like a hacky and unintended way to alter this library. What is your top-level script, `run.py`, based on? Also, you should probably explain this approach in the question (and link to that GitHub).

Comment: @CrazyChucky Please see revised question. Hope that helps to kick off the modification to the code.

Comment: The minimal reproducible examples are posted. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

`import` can be used to run code, as well as import libraries. When you want to run the code in another file, just use this syntax:

```
import fileName
```

Where fileName is the name of the file. Remember to omit the `*.py`.

In a sence, `import` only runs code, as with libraries, that code is usually just defining functions.

Comment: please see revised question.

Comment: Could you please take a look the minimal reproducible examples? Thanks.